# Error 405: Method not Allowed on DELETE and PUT

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, crud

I followed this **[spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/)** and everything worked fine. After this, I decided to add **delete** and **modify** funcionalities. I've implemented them, but when I try to use them, I got the following **error**:

> {"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/demo/delete"}
>
> {"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/demo/modify"}

The commands that I'm executing:

```
curl localhost:8080/demo/delete -d name=First

curl localhost:8080/demo/modify -d name=First -d email=abc@gmail.com

//if the name doesn't exist in both methods, it will return "Nonexistent user!"
```

Below are the following code of:

**MainController.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller 
@RequestMapping(path="/demo") 
public class MainController {
    @Autowired 
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping(path="/add") 
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name, 
           @RequestParam String email) {

        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "Saved\n";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    /* ----------------- NEW METHODS THAT I'VE CREATED ----------------- */

    @DeleteMapping(path="/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam String name) throws Exception {
        if(userRepository.findByName(name).equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("Nonexistent user!\n");
        }
        userRepository.deleteByName(name);
        return "User successfully deleted!\n";
    }

    @PutMapping(path="/modify")
    public String modify(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email) throws Exception {
        if(userRepository.findByName(name).equals(null)) {
            System.out.println("Nonexistent user!\n");
        }

        userRepository.deleteByName(name);
        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "User successfully modified!\n";
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**UserRepository.java**

```
package com.example.accessingdatamysql;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.example.accessingdatamysql.User;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

    public User findByName(String name);
    public void deleteByName(String name);
}
```

I've no idea what's happening here. I've searched for other similar questions like that with the same error but none of them solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing the calls with the method `POST` rather than `DELETE` for `/demo/delete` and `PUT` for `/demo/modify`.

```
{"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/demo/delete"}

{"status":405,"error":"Method Not Allowed","message":"Request method 'POST' not supported","path":"/demo/modify"}
```

You are not showing how are you executing those failing calls, but for example, if you are using a GUI client such Postman to simulate the calls, check that you are selecting the proper HTTP method.
And if you are using the `curl` library in the terminal pay attention to the method set:

```
curl -X "DELETE" http://your.url/demo/delete ...
```

```
curl -X "PUT" http://your.url/demo/modify ...
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer! So, the methods now are working, but they are returning **error 404 not found**, do you know why? Also I've added in my question the commands that I'm executing (I'm using `curl`)

Comment: You are welcome! Though you should open a new question with the problems you are getting after solving your initial question.

Answer (score 2):

After following @Dez's answer, the problem was solved but I was getting other error:

> No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'persist' call

I solved it by adding `@Transactional` on **DELETE** and **PUT** methods in **MainController** class:

```
@DeleteMapping(path="/delete")
@Transactional //added
public void delete(@RequestParam String name) throws Exception { (...) }

@PutMapping(path="/modify")
@Transactional //added
public void modify(@RequestParam String name, @RequestParam String email) throws Exception { (...) }
```

And modified the exception throwing condition, that was always returning `false`:

```
if(userRepository.findByName(name).equals(null)) {
     throw new Exception("Nonexistent user!");
}
```

to

```
if(userRepository.findByName(name) == null) {
     throw new Exception("Nonexistent user!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how `@DeleteMapping` and `@PutMapping` work. These annotations are shortcuts to `@RequestMapping` with `method` attribute fixed to `DELETE` or `PUT` correspondingly. To allow multiple HTTP methods for an endpoint you should list them explicitly:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/modify", method = { RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.POST })
public String modify(...){
   ...
}
```